# Есть ли брокеры сообщений где можно сохранять объекты?

Tags: golang, брокер-сообщений

Прошу не пинать если вопрос глупый.

В пет-проекте понадобился брокер сообщений. Я пробовал натс но он работает только со строками.

А есть ли такие брокеры, которые умеют работать гибридно(pub/sub+p2p) и, главное, могут сохранять не только строки а ещё и объекты(структуры, мапы и т.д). P2P в приоритете, а гибрид необязательно но это задел на будущий функционал.

Да, знаю, что можно запаковать объект в json и сохранять как строку, но это накладные расходы на распаковку/запаковку каждой транзакции.

Да, работа ведётся с транзакциями, которые один пользователь запрашивает у другого. Может кто то считает что брокеры для этого не лучший вариант и знает вариант получше?

Comment: Какой ЯП? Может есть что-то специфичное под ваш ЯП. Вы же хотите сохранять структуры.

Comment: @Alpensin golang. Добавлю метку

Comment: @Alpensin нашел как сделать из структуры массив байтов, пробую некий gob пакет из encoding

Comment: @Alpensin будут делать через jwt tokens. Хранить в брокере токен и доставать из него palyoad пока что-то получше не придумаю.

Comment: А что за брокер? В кафке например есть возможность использовать protobuf или Avro. Может и тот что вы используете поддерживает что-то подобное.